# How can I see my own questions and answers in the iOS app?

Tags: support, ios-app

The developers of the Stack Exchange iOS App seem to have forgotten something which is available in the web site: a view where I can see my own questions and answers.

Or is it there and I just haven't found it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to see all your questions and answers *across all sites*, but you can see them for each site. In the latest version of the app (1.3.0):

1. Tap the top-left hamburger to pull out the left tray.
2. Tap the first item (your name).
3. Under the header banner, tap the site you want to view. (To view all your sites, click All *N* sites in the bottom right corner of the panel, right above Recent Activity)
4. On the top right of the Top Posts subpanel, click All *N* posts to view a list of all your questions and answers.

This is just a shortcut to a search for **user: (your user id)**, so you could also view the site in question, and enter that query in the search box at the top.

Answer (score 7):

Click on your icon on the top left side, it will lead you to your profile.

The first box under your tag line is your top posts. At the bottom of it there's a link to "All  posts".